# git works fine but tortoisegit aborts with "cannot spawn sh" + "unable to fork"

Tags: tortoisegit

I can not clone or fetch with tortoisegit. The output window gives these errors :

```
error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

But **if I run the git command line** shown in the output window **it works well**.
So the problem seems in tortoise's configuration ?

Some informations :

- I worked without problem with git 1.9.5 and tortoisegit 1.8.15.0. I upgraded to git-2.5.1 and the problem appears. I go back to git-1.9.5 but the problem remains.
- The repository is a directory on a machine on the local network. I do not use ssh.
- I have no problem to fetch from repositories on internet
- I reinstall tortoisegit without more success...

Do you know from where the problem comes ?
Or do you know how to clean the stored configuration of tortoisegit ?

Thanks for your help.

**[Edit]**
I have just changed the git.exe path in tortoise settings (settings/general/git.exe path). It what set to *C:\Program Files\Git\bin\libexec\git-core*. I change it to *C:\Program Files\Git\bin*.
And it works again.
There is 4 directories with git.exe :

- C:\Program Files\Git\bin
- C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
- C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
- C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core

**Which one to use with tortoisegit on windows7 64 ?**
**[/Edit]**

Answer (score 6):

The installation of git-2.5.1 changes the tortoisegit's path to git.exe.
Setting it again to C:\Program Files\Git\bin is a solution for me.

But I don't know why there are 4 git.exe and why the installation set the wrong one... A bug ?

Comment: I had the same issue, I suspect due to an install of msysgit after TortoiseGit. Deinstalling everything and then reinstalling msysgit + Tortoisegit (in that order) did not help. Also, I couldn't get wincred to show up in the settings. After switching the TortoiseGit setting as you suggested, my issues were gone.

Comment: Thanks for your comment : it is nice to know that I am not alone and that the same workaround works.

Comment: Solved my issue where TotoiseGit failed to store passwords (wincred).